# All applications use Java Runtime Environment only open after disabling all windows 7 visual effects

Tags: windows-7, java

My all applications use Java Runtime Environment only can open after disabling all windows 7 visual effects. Otherwise they will throw this exception : "Could not initialize class javax.swing.UIManager"
Any idea to fix this problem ? I don't want to turn off all windows 7 beautiful effects.

Comment: You must provide the entire stack trace, as well as the code containing the line (in your code) where the exception is thrown.

Comment: Problem solved. It caused by cleartype text issue. Just adjust cleartype text then they work again.

Comment: @IT-Fan: can you please answer the question yourself and then accept that answer? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.